# How to populate MVC partial view form fields from JQuery table row click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Jquery DataTable that contains users. Its generated by a JQuery AJAX call to a Json result method in my MVC controller and iterates over the result to generate the rows in the table. Now I need to be able to click on the row, and have it make the MVC partial view form go from hidden to visible and populate the form with the user's data which will be with another Json call. My question is how do I get that ID value passed to another Json method to retrieve the data for that user then make the partial visible upon being populated with the user's data. Currently the partial view is set in a div on the main partial and called using `@Html.Partial("TeamMember")`

**DataTable Code**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("TeamData", {Id: 636},
            function (json) {
                var tr;
                for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                    tr = $('<tr/>');
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].Id + "</td>")
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].FullName + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].Lan_Id + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].CurrDept + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].Email + "</td>");
                    $('#mTeamTable').append(tr);
                }
                $('#mTeamTable').DataTable();
            });
    });
```

[image: DataTable]

[image: User Data Partial]

Comment: IMHO You should return a partial view which already has data bound, instead of 
 making another ajax call. Like `return Partial("_UserDataView",model)`

Comment: Change to `tr = $('<tr data-id="' + json[i].Id + '"/>');` then on your tr.onclick use `$(this).data("id")`

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you! That worked.  If you post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have HTML view like this:

```
<table id="mTeamTable">
   ...
</table>

<div id="partialView">
    @Html.Partial("TeamMember")
</div>
```

And a controller method returning JSON data like this:

```
public JsonResult TeamData(string Id)
{
    // query team data
    var member = GetTeamData();

    // return JSON string
    return Json(member, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then, you need to configure 2 actions: when JSON data received & when clicking `DataTable` row to show partial view. Both of actions illustrated in code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    // hide partial view div first
    $('#partialView').hide();

    $.getJSON("TeamData", { Id: 636 }, function (json) {
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
           tr = $('<tr data-id="' + json[i].Id + '"/>');
           tr.append("<td>" + json[i].Id + "</td>");
           tr.append("<td>" + json[i].FullName + "</td>");
           tr.append("<td>" + json[i].Lan_Id + "</td>");
           tr.append("<td>" + json[i].CurrDept + "</td>");
           tr.append("<td>" + json[i].Email + "</td>");
           $('#mTeamTable').append(tr);
        }
        $('#mTeamTable').DataTable();
    });

    // this section just an example to handle row click event
    // if the table contains tbody element, use $('#mTeamTable tbody')
    // see https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html for row event handling
    $('#mTeamTable').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var table = $('#mTeamTable').DataTable();
        var data = table.row(this).data();

        // call partial view here
        // use of @Url.Action in url part is recommended
        $.get("TeamMember", { Id: data[0] } , function () {

            // show partial view div
            $('#partialView').show();
        });
    });
});
```

Additionally, you may need to set up a controller action method which returns partial view with viewmodel as given below:

```
public PartialViewResult TeamMember(string Id)
{
    // query team member
    var member = GetTeamMember();

    // put query results on a viewmodel, say it Member
    var teamMember = new Member()
    {
        Id = member.Id,
        FullName = member.FullName,
        ...
        Email = member.Email
    };

    // return partial view with viewmodel properties
    return PartialView("TeamMember", model);
}
```

Perhaps this is far from perfect, but at least explain key points which should be consider to handle datatable row clicking event.